# Is it possible to get two inputs of different datatypes in one scanf() in c?

Tags: c, input, scanf

I want to get the command as input like

```
<char><number><number>
```

so is it possible to get it using one `scanf()` function in c ?

```
int i,j; 
char c; 
scanf("%c%d%d",&c, &i, &j);
```

Comment: `scanf("%c%1d%1d", &c, &i, &j);`

Comment: Your scanf will read something other than 2 for j. @BLUEPIXY gave you the correct way to write your scanf.

Comment: `scanf("%c%1d%1d",&c, &i, &j);`
`printf ("C = %c i = %d j = %d\n", c, i, j);`

gives me

`# ./chksize.o`
`A12`
`C = A i = 1 j = 2`

Comment: Presumably you meant `<char><digit><digit>`, in which case @BLUEPIXY has answered it. But if you really mean number instead of digit (where number could be 10, (or 2345, or...) then you have to adjust the length specifier to 2d or 4d or ?? assuming you know the number of digits in each number. If you don't, how do you interpret "23456" ? Is it "2" followed by "3456", or "23" followed by "456", or ... etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that will work because the compiler will consider that as something together rather than one character, and two integers but to take the input in this format  i.e. to make the compiler understand that you can take the entire line as a string and then parse the string to extract the character and the integers

```
char a[1000],c; int x,y;
scanf("%s",a);
c = a[0];
x = a[1] - '0';
y = a[2] - '0';
```

Also, @BLUEPIXY gave even better solution to your problem!

Comment: `scanf("%s",a);` is about as safe a `gets(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get  more than 1 input in 1 scanf as the following:

```
char ch, string[100];
int number;

printf("--char--/--number--/--string--");
scanf(" %c%d %s",&ch,&number,&string[0]); // -> be careful about the whitespaces

printf("%c\n",ch);
printf("%d\n",number);
printf("%s\n",string);
```

You dont need to use spaces or \n to enter your input.